# Need to Delete whole database in Jhipster using liquibase

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I am working on jhipster spring using angular js and database as "liquibase".Why We need to delete whole database when we have done change in our db-changelog.xml?.if i have add one field to old table in database then i have a get exception t_user table is already exist.which mean we have to remove t_user table or loss our data.please help and provide any other way to change our database without deleting whole database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday, we released the version 0.11; which supports the generation of the changelogs containing only your changes. The changes are applied automatically on the database. No need to drop your database now.

Try it. http://jhipster.github.io/2014/02/19/jhipster-release-0.11.0.html

Answer (score 2):

I have not used jhipster at all, but normal liquibase usage is to not keep dropping the database but rather append new changeSets to your db-changelog.xml file. For example, if you originally had a  changeSet and need to add a column you append an  changeSet. That way you don't lose data and liquibase keeps track of which changes have been ran against your databases.